# Java servlet problem after creating and merging from differnt PC's

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am working on `Servlet` using Netbeans. I have servlets on different PCs. When I am trying to merge all in one project, it is giving me error, "module has not been deployed".

If any one knows, please help.

Comment: have you compiled all servlets before merging?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of an underlying error in your code. Check your Servlet Container (Tomcat, Jboss, etc...) logs for more information